# National Centres Environmental Information Access Data Service API

Tags: weather-api

Is there any full listing of the **National Centres for Environmental Information API** Dataset and datatypes.

Specifically I am looking for the dataset average daily with the datatypes max/min temp, precipitation.

So my endpoint would look like:

```
dataset={dataset}&dataTypes={datatypes}&boundingBox=49.795,-2.073,49.183,-0.992
&startDate=2017-01-01&endDate=2017-12-31&&format=json
```

Many thanks

I've searched https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/ but can only find codes for ocean data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process

```
  dataset=daily-summaries&boundingBox=boundingBox=49.795,-2.073,49.183,-0.992
```

retrieves meta data on stations with daily-summaries

Then with a selected stationID

```
  dataset=daily-summaries&startDate=2017-01-01&endDate=2018-12-31&dataTypes=TAVG,PRCP&stations={selectedID}&format=json
```